# Append zip files in amazon using s3 php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Can we add some files(append) inside zip file which is already uploaded into amazon s3 ? using php sdk?

```
  $result = $s3->uploadPart(array(
                                    'Bucket'     => $as3_bucket,
                                    'Key'        => $as3_file,
                                    'UploadId'   => $uploadId,
                                    'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                                    'Body'       => fread($file, 5 * 1024 * 1024),
                                ));
```

This is from client side. What I'm trying is that after uploaded 5 MB   `'Body'       => fread($file, 5 * 1024 * 1024)` I cut the call then again open the file uploading from another 5MB. like this I'm uploading data. problem is the last only 5Mb of data gets stored in that file(after finished connection i checked the file size in s3  ). I'm reading 5MB from the file according to the how many times called .

so no problems in `fread` , problem is in `multipart upload` ,I cannot continue uploading where I stopped. Whenever I tried for next call , the fresh `zip` created even i'm using same `upload ID` , but in `Amazon s3.php` file we have `'seekTo'` option , to append files ! like this `amazon s3 sdk php` also having any function like this?